# Add a class ONLY the first tme scrolled into view

Tags: jquery, scroll

I would like to add a class to a div when scrolled into view the FIRST TIME ONLY.  I'm using the code from [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z3xTU/15/) to add the class on scroll - but it does it every time the div is scrolled into view and not just the 1st time.

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.class').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            $(this).addClass('in-view')
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: If the element never loses the class, what harm is there in addClass being called on it again? it won't have any effect. In either case, simply use a :not selector to omit elements with `.class` that also have `.in-view` and it won't needlessly iterate over them.

Comment: Well in my particular case - there were other elements on the page that would remove the class when hovered (which had a transform scale property) so as soon as you would scroll again it would add the class again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a secondary class to signify if an element should not be processed again.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //only check classes that do not have our class flag
  $('.class:not(.previously-in-view)').each(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
      //add the in-view class and the class flag to exclude it from future logic
      $(this).addClass('in-view').addClass('previously-in-view');
    }
  });
});
```